# Use iOS tableView to make menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app is a tab bar application. I have a more tab, and in that more tab I would like to have a table view with each row pointing to another screen. I thought I could accomplish this in storyboard by just control dragging each static row to a view controller but when I click the table rows in the simulator it crashes.

1. How do I use iOS TableView to make a simple menu with static rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Embed the table view in a navigation controller.